# How to remove redundant rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have loaded a data into dataframe but there are redundant rows in the data frame which I want to remove.

What is the easiest way to invoke pandas to remove the rows? Please see the attached image below. The rows in red boxes are the ones I want to remove

Thanks for the help and guidance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for select  rows where columns names is not same like values in columns:

```
df = df[df['Month'].ne('Month')]
```

Or [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) alternative:

```
df = df.query("Month != 'Month'")
```

EDIT:

You can also chain all columns comparisons, but I think not necessary, nice working testing only one column:

```
df = df[df['Month'].ne('Month') & df['Currency'].ne('Currency') & ...]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use pandas `drop_duplicates` which returns only the dataframe’s unique values.

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks. Just run the code. It remove the 3rd red boxed data but not the 2nd. 
any idea why? trying to understand the workings of python :)

Comment: It removes the duplicates from the excel file. First row is considered as header, `2nd red boxed` is first occurrence and `3rd red boxed data`is real duplicate as per pandas data frame. If you want to remove 2nd box, you need to add `header=False` while loading the dataframe.